# pandas replacing or updating an entire row conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
    Name    Status   Data
0   Mike    yes      123
1   Bob     no       456
2   Ted     yes      789
3   Fred    yes
```

Now I have a new `df`:

```
0 Mike no 345
1 Fred no 123
```

How do I update the first `df` to reflect changes? Is this a replace or join function?

Output:

```
    Name    Status   Data
0   Mike    no       345
1   Bob     no       456
2   Ted     yes      789
3   Fred    no       123
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `update` and `merge`
**NOTE:** I limited `df` to just the column I want to merge on with double brackets to ensure my result stays a dataframe `df[['Name']]`.  Then I do a left merge with `dfn` to add the columns I want to update.  `'left'` ensures I get the same index as `df` and can happily `update` with no issues.

```
df.update(df[['Name']].merge(dfn, 'left'))
df

   Name Status   Data
0  Mike     no  345.0
1   Bob     no  456.0
2   Ted    yes  789.0
3  Fred     no  123.0
```

---

#### Advice

If you want to use `'Name'` as an index, set it as the index.

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
dfn = dfn.set_index('Name')
```

Then this turns into

#### `pd.DataFrame.combine_first`

Pipelined copy

```
dfn.combine_first(df)

     Status   Data
Name              
Bob      no  456.0
Fred     no  123.0
Mike     no  345.0
Ted     yes  789.0
```

#### `pd.DataFrame.update`

In place

```
df.update(dfn)
df

     Status   Data
Name              
Bob      no  456.0
Fred     no  123.0
Mike     no  345.0
Ted     yes  789.0
```